# Memory allocation pattern - Linux

Tags: linux

Im very much confused about the pattern at which memory is allocated in  linux system..to understand that i made a simple program which i have listed below :

```
main()
{  
 int a=5;
 char b='B';
 int c=10;
 int *p=NULL;
 char *q=NULL;
 int *r=NULL;
 p = new int;
 q = new char;
 r = new int;
 printf("\n The address of a : %p ",&a);
 printf("\n The address of b : %p ",&b);
 printf("\n The address of c : %p ",&c);
 int *p=NULL;
 int *q=NULL;
 p = new int;
 q = new int;
 printf("\n The address of a is %p ",&a);
 printf("\n The address of b is %p ",&b);
 printf("\n The address of p : %p ",&p);
 printf("\n The address of q : %p",&q);
 printf("\n The address at which new1 memory is allocated :  %p ",p);
 printf("\n The address at which new2 memory is allocated :  %p ",q);
 }
```

Output on a Red Hat Linux 7.3 X86 PC:

```
The address of a : 0xbffffa74
The address of b : 0xbffffa73
The address of c : 0xbffffa6c
The address of p : 0xbffffa68
The address of q : 0xbffffa64
The address of r : 0xbffffa60
The address at which new1 memory is allocated :  0x8050638
The address at which new2 memory is allocated :  0x8050648
The address at which new3 memory is allocated :  0x8050658
```

Now below are some of my question.Pls help me in understanding..

1.why is there a difference of 7 bytes between c and b on stack?

2.Why is there a difference of 10 bytes for every variable allocated on heap?

3.Whenever i run this executable,i get the same address..how is that possible?

Please help me in understanding this behaviour..

Comment: You are printing the address of pointers...

Comment: Hi @OliCharlesworth .. which line u r pointing to? First im printing the address of the pointer, then after dynamic memory allocation im printing the content of the pointer..which inturn will be the address of the new operator.. pls clarify..

Comment: 1) required alignment constraints 2) allocator typically allocates more than requested for allocator-specific internal metadata needed to maintain the heap 3) "standardized" process memory address-space layout

Comment: Hi @twalberg.. thaks for your reply.. is there any referenced theory available? i would like to go learn those concepts? is it a part of operating systems?

Comment: The best "theory" is probably the source code for your C library... And maybe the x86/x86_64 programmers reference manuals... And the Linux kernel source code / documentation...